# How to use .dll class files in visual studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have download a folder of .dll files from codeplex.com to add and use a class in my project but I don't know how to use them.It is about zip files with c# and here is the link:
http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Thanks!

Comment: One word: References
More words: Get a C#/VB.NET basics book and read it

Comment: select add reference from Visual Studio Solution Explorer and add those dll files .. and then use it in your code by including namespace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the DLL and try the sample code:

```
 using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
 {
     // add this map file into the "images" directory in the zip archive
     zip.AddFile("c:\\images\\personal\\7440-N49th.png", "images");
     // add the report into a different directory in the archive
     zip.AddFile("c:\\Reports\\2008-Regional-Sales-Report.pdf", "files");
     zip.AddFile("ReadMe.txt");
     zip.Save("MyZipFile.zip");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add them as references in your project/solution and include `using` statements to the namespaces in each that you wish to use.

The classes will then be available for usage in your application.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when you want to use a library, you will want to start by reading the documentation.

You can usually find a link to it if you scan the library's home page. In this case, "DOCUMENTATION" is a tab at the top of the screen. If you [click it](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/documentation), you land at a page with two links:

- [Reference doc](http://dotnetzip.herobo.com/DNZHelp/Index.html)
- [Lots of examples](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Documentation), for VB, C#, Powershell, and so on.

Both of those pages would be good places to start reading to learn how to use the library.

They'll probably tell you to download `Ionic.Zip.dll`, add a reference to it to your project, and then create an instance of the `ZipFile` object. Any good book on your language dialect of choice will have a section on how to add references to external libraries.